# Format date when user type the value

Tags: javascript, regex, date, replace, format

small issue with date.
I'm trying to format a date when user type the value. So if someone type, for example, 2017, the input auto complete with / (slash) and then the user fill the month and the day.
Currently I have this code, but doesn't work as expected. I mean, the date must have the format: YYYY/MM/DD.

```
$('input[name*=expire]').bind('keyup', function() {
    // Instance vars.
    var $this = $(this),
      value = $this.val();

    // Clear value to inter number.
    value = value.replace(/\D/g,"");

    value = value.replace(/(\d{4})/,"$1");
    value = value.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)/,"$1/$2");
    value = value.replace(/(\d{2})(\d)$/,"$1/$2");

    // Set interval to map click action.
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.val(value);
    }, 1);
  });
```

Using this code, for some reason the return is `11/11111/1` instead of `1111/11/11`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that changing the value of the input while the user is typing in it moves the cursor, making it difficult to edit existing values. Anyway, it looks like your first `.replace()` doesn't do anything at all because the replacement string is an exact copy of the matched string. The second `.replace()` adds a `/` after the first two digits. The third `.replace()` matches on three digits at the end of the string and inserts a `/` before the last digit.

Comment: This type of auto-formatting is extremely difficult to get right. You'll likely end up with a lot of code and clunky UI for zero benefit. Just let the user type something and present non-blocking messages to advise if something's not right.

Comment: Willian, you mention `YYYY/MM/DD` format, but why do you use `\d{2}` only in the regex? I assumed you were after `YY/MM/DD` format?

Comment: I have removed my answer since I am not sure what you need. However, `pattern="\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}"` seems the best work around for this.